# Nodejs async good practices

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Imagine you are creating a framework for nodejs.

Is there any good practices to handle sync/async code.

I'm talking about the sync-to-async problem as follows:

All over your libraries you have code that from the beginning is sync for example:

```
function validate(email) {
    return email.match(/regex-blah/)
}
```

When you need some IO async operation inside the functions they should become async (with async keyword or promises). Doesnt matter.

```
async function validate(email){
    ...
}
```

What matters is that all callers (called "x") to "validate" should become async also - and all callers to "x"

Which becomes very hard to support and maintain.

This could be a problem in a client side framework also i think.

Is there any good rules to avoid that problem.

Thanks

Comment: There's only one rule, think ahead, and expose clean interface. If you expose the sync `validate` method, it will not be possible to change it to async without breaking contract. Otherwise, if you expect it to become async in future, make it async right now and wrap your return value in a `Promise.resolve(...)`

Comment: This means that I should write all functions as async because i don't know what will happen in the future.

Comment: Probably no, making all sync functions as async would be overkill. If you are writing the framework you are in control of what happens in future. For eg, lets say this sync validate function was exposed. And tomorrow you get a requirement for validate-email-from-server. At that point, you won't be able to change existing function. Instead, you will have to add `validateEmailAtServer` function separately. It probably wouldn't have made sense to change existing function anyway.